# Generate json with multiple records from DB (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have the following code which is expected to return complex JSON containing data selected from DB by multiple parameters and includes data from other models:

```
def search
params[:beacon] = [{ 'id' => 1, 'prox_uuid' => 12345453453 }, { 'id' => 2, 'prox_uuid' => 5345634564536435 }]
beacons = Beacon.includes(:ads, :venue).where("id in (?) and proximity_uuid in (?)", params[:beacon][:ids], params[:beacon][:prox_uuids])
data = beacons.map { |beacon| {
      id: beacon.id,
      name: beacon.name,
      :venue => {
          id: beacon.venue.id,
          name: beacon.venue.name,
          logo: URI.join(request.base_url, beacon.venue.logo.url).to_s
      },
      ads: beacon.ads.inject([]) do |sum, add|
        sum << {
          id: add.id,
          title: add.name,
          cover: URI.join(request.base_url, add.file_url.url).to_s,
          price: add.price,
          description: add.description
        }
      end
    }
  }
  render json: data.to_json
end
```

`params[:beacon] = [{ 'id' => 1, 'prox_uuid' => 12345453453 }, { 'id' => 2, 'prox_uuid' => 5345634564536435 }]` is a placeholder for array of parameters coming from POST request.

The problem is that I receive the following error at the query line:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

I also tried going through the array of parameters in the loop and querying each record however json generates only the last one.

Comment: are you intentionally wanting to build the json like this?  If this isn't an exercise, you should look at a serializer (jbuilder/active_model_serializers) as this is what they're made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `params[:beacon][:ids]` and `params[:beacon][:prox_uuids]` but `params[:beacon]` is an array, and so should be indexed by integer, eg. `params[:beacon][0]`.  So the error is telling you that `:ids` (a Symbol) cannot be implicitly converted to an Integer in order to correctly reference into the `params[:beacon]` array.

Comment: Thanks, Smathy! I tried to convert array into hash but with not much luck to solve the final goal... will be trying again.

Comment: FWIW, to get all the `id`s from the hashes within that array you could just do this: `params[:beacon].map{|e|e['id']}` I'll leave the `prox_uuid`s up to you :)